# How can I create a bar-chart which has multiple bars for each label in MS Excell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I'm trying to create a chart like the following image, but I cant seem to find the correct way of doing so.
Here is the image :
[image]

As you can see there are only 3 labels while there are 6 bars, twice the number of labels. Each label has two bars, which show its default (former) performance and a new bar representing its new performance using the new library. How can I implement this in MS Excel?
Simply defining 6 rows for each bar, does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in excel you use the below data layout:

```
;2016;2017
alex;5;10
goog;5;10
vgg;5;12
```

this data is a CSV file, each ";" (semi-column) represents a field in excel (top-left (a1) remains empty.

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I can remove the 0 and not displaying it? 
I want only 1x,2x and 3x . Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

A Pivot Chart is what you want. Take a look at my data first:

[image]

All you have to do is select all of the data, select the Insert ribbon tab, then PivotChart.

[image]

Select New Worksheet or Existing Worksheet (whichever you want)

Put your fields into legend, axis, and values as follows:

[image]

You can then clean up the chart much like any chart, adding axis labels, title, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much, How can I specify a x next to each label on the vertical axis ? and also omit 0 ? (I dont want to start from 1, I just need to remove 0, and have 1x,2x and 3x instead of 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Well adding the x I am unsure of because if you input 1x, 2x, 3x it will no longer treat them as numbers. You could do percentages though instead. If you want to start from something other than 0, change the graphs Y Major axis min value to something else

Comment: Thanks, percentage didn't work however, I used, Custom and in the field below it I wrote `dx`, it now prints 0x,1x,2x and 3x. 
Now I need to get rid of the 0x! setting the major Y to 1 doesnt help. it just starts from 1 and therefore 3 bars having 1 would disappear.

Comment: Ok what I turned up doing was to hide the 0x by placing a rectangle (from figures). Thank you for your help